# Apache Zeppelin Spark notebook is showing status running even though it is not running. Why?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Why is it showing status `running`?

Should I explicitly exit Zeppelin notebook? Should we write an exit statement at the end?

Comment: how did you decide that "the notebook is not running"? Did you check the spark UI and found no job running there? Can you see any running context on the spark UI?

Comment: Yes I have seen the UI there it is showing that notebook was not running.But it's status is Running.

Comment: can you check zeppelin spark interpreter log and see whether you can find any exception/clue there? Logs could be found under `<zeppelin-root>/incubator-zeppelin/logs` directory as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

There is no exit statement for Zeppelin. Status box will inform you when the job is done. In the meantime, you can check the Zeppelin or Spark logs.

Comment: In Zeppelin spark notebook . I runned one paragraph and the job is not completed and not able to stop that also.Due to that I am not able to run any of the other paragraphs.literally the zeppelin notebook is not working. What should I have to do in that cases?

Comment: First and the simplest thing to do would be to restart Zeppelin and Spark, and then use a smaller data set or less complex computations.

Comment: Where will be the option of restarting the Zeppelin and Spark ? I have used AWS EMR to maintain. Can you please tell me the location where restart option will be ?

Comment: Where can I check the Zeppelin/Spark logs?